# 英語が残っている：○○ people chatting

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

近頃、下のような感じでサイドバーにチャットへのリンクが出るようになりましたが、タイトル部分が和訳できていません。https://ja.traducir.win で検索してもヒットしませんでした。

この部分を翻訳できるようにして頂けませんでしょうか。

[image: サイドバーのチャット部分のスクリーンショットです]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/dashboard/) の方で見つけたので、取り急ぎは翻訳を提案しておきました。

Comment: ありがとうございますm_ _m  https://ja.traducir.win/string/10802 オーバーライドを防ぐためにこちらからお願いできれば嬉しいです、すみません

Comment: traducir.win にも反映しておきました。`Ignore!`ラベルが付いてるのが気になりますね。(まだ使い方を完全に理解できてません…)